# Is there a workaround for overloading the assignment operator in C#?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Unlike C++, in C# you can't overload the assignment operator.

I'm doing a custom Number class for arithmetic operations with very large numbers and I want it to have the look-and-feel of the built-in numerical types like int, decimal, etc. I've overloaded the arithmetic operators, but the assignment remains...

Here's an example:

```
Number a = new Number(55); 
Number b = a; //I want to copy the value, not the reference
```

Is there a workaround for that issue?

Comment: Explain the issue (why you need it).

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should've been more specific. I'm doing a custom Number class for arithmetic operations with very large numbers and I want it to have the look-and-feel of the built-in numerical types like int, decimal, etc. I've overloaded the arithmetic operators, but the assignment remains...

Comment: Thanks - i've added your comment to the question itself.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you'd like to be able to write?

Comment: Here's an example:
Number a = new Number(55);
Number b = a;
And I want it to copy the value, not the reference.

Comment: structs are value based by all i know. can't you use "struct" for your numbers?

Comment: @litb: That's an idea, but I think I have too much functionality in the Number class to make it a struct. Thanks, anyway :)

Comment: In what way do you think you have "too much functionality [...] to make it a struct"? Do you mean it's too large in terms of memory usage?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: No, just too many methods in there... Kind of doesn't feel like a struct.

Comment: Look at DateTime and TimeSpan. Plenty of methods there. If it's effectively an atomic value, then it should probably be a struct. Numbers almost always fall into this category.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes, you pretty much have me convinced. Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's still not at all clear to me that you really need this. Either:

- Your Number type should be a struct (which is probable - numbers are the most common example of structs). Note that all the types you want your type to act like (int, decimal etc) are structs.

or:

- Your Number type should be immutable, making every mutation operation return a new instance, in which case you don't need the data to be copied on assignment anyway. (In fact, your type should be immutable whether or not it's a struct. Mutable structs are evil, and a number certainly shouldn't be a mutable reference type.)

Comment: Yes, maybe the struct idea is good. And I like the immutability option - it was suggested in another answer. Thanks, I'll try what you propose.

Comment: Mutable structs might be evil but the C# team thought they were ok for Enumerators. I think it's more correct to say it as a general rule.

Comment: Mutability is not evil, if you can prevent object sharing. This can be done by implementing linear types which requires some form of assignment overloading. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_type_system.

Answer (score 42):

you can use the 'implicit' keyword to create an overload for the assignment:

Suppose you have a type like Foo, that you feel is implicitly convertable from a string.
You would write the following static method in your Foo class:

```
public static implicit operator Foo(string normalString)
{
    //write your code here to go from string to Foo and return the new Foo.
}
```

Having done that, you can then use the following in your code:

```
Foo x = "whatever";
```

Comment: Cool, this answers a question I was going ot ask ;)

Comment: Doesn't that only work if you are trying to assign one type to another?  It's an implicit cast, after all. I don't think that would help if you wanted to assign `Number` to `Number`.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood - That was exactly what i was looking for! Much appreciated!

Comment: @drew-noakes: If you want to assign Number to Number, and Number is a struct, you get the desired effect with the default assignment operator anyway: Assign by value.

Comment: @Nilzor, in such a case you get a copy of the value as you say, but the OP wants to control that process somehow with their own code.  I don't think that's possible unless you're adapting between two types.  So it's slightly different to what you can do in C++.

Comment: @jonathon wood - thanks. what i was after too.  very helpful in 3D math

Answer (score 6):

You won't be able to work around it having the C++ look, since a = b; has other semantics in C++ than in C#. In C#, a = b; makes a point to the same object like b. In C++, a = b changes the content of a. Both has their ups and downs. It's like you do

```
MyType * a = new MyType();
MyType * b = new MyType(); 
a = b; /* only exchange pointers. will not change any content */
```

In C++ (it will lose the reference to the first object, and create a memory leak. But let's ignore that here). You cannot overload the assign operator in C++ for that either.

The workaround is easy:

```
MyType a = new MyType();
MyType b = new MyType();

// instead of a = b
a.Assign(b);
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm not a C# developer

You could create a write-only-property like this. then do a.Self = b; above.

```
public MyType Self {
    set {
        /* copy content of value to this */
        this.Assign(value);
    }
}
```

Now, this is **not** good. Since it violates the principle-of-least-surprise (POLS). One wouldn't expect a to change if one does a.Self = b;

Comment: Maybe I could do it that way. But what I meant was - a workaround that gives me the real look-and-feel of assignment operator overloading, so I ca literally say:

MyType a = new MyType();
MyType b = new MyType();
a = b;

and it performs some custom assignment logic.

Comment: The description of why it doesn't work is spot-on. As you suggest, though, the Self property idea is not so good,

Comment: "In C++, a = b changes the content of a." - thats not entirely correct. it depends on whether a and b are pointers or not.  a=b could make a point to b or it could call your = overload and copy the contents to a.

Comment: @MickyDuncan Eh.. it is entirely correct. What do you think the content of a and b IS if they are pointers? In what sense does "only copying the pointer" differ from "copying the content" when the content IS a pointer?

Comment: @TheDag c++ = assignment can either make a pointer point to the same object OR change the contents depending on the variable type.  One did not establish we were talking about just pointers

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making a copy of the data when passing the reference you could make the class immutable. When the class is immutable having multiple references to it isn't a problem since it can't be changed.

Operations that changes the data would of course return new instances.

Answer (score 2):

An earlier post suggested this:

> public static implicit operator Foo(string normalString) { }

I tried this approach... but to make it work you need this:

public static implicit operator Foo(Foo original)  { }

and the compiler won't let you have an implicit conversion function from your exact type, nor from any base type of yourself. That makes sense since it would be a backdoor way of overriding the assignment operator, which C# doesn't want to allow.

Comment: "The implicit keyword is used to declare an implicit user-defined type conversion operator. Use it to enable implicit conversions between a user-defined type and another type, ..." - MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked for myself :

```
public class MyTestClass
{
   private int a;
   private string str;

   public MyTestClass()
   {
      a = 0;
      str = null;
   }

   public MyTestClass(int a, string str)
   {
      this.a = a;
      this.str = str;
   }

   public MyTestClass Clone
   {
      get
      {
         return new MyTestClass(this.a, this.str);
      }
   }
}
```

Somewhere else in the code :

```
MyTestClass test1 = new MyTestClass(5, "Cat");
MyTestClass test2 = test1.Clone;
```

Answer (score -4):

Maybe what you're looking for can be solved using C# accessors.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786(v=vs.71).aspx