# Why aren't assignment operators overloadable in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, operator-overloading

Why aren't the assignment operators (+=, -=, *=, /=) overloadable in VB.NET?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - Yup, found that myself.  Could you point out where in that article it says why the assignment operators aren't overloadable?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - Thought maybe you'd read something I'd missed.

Comment: Added some stuff about implicit/explicit converters that might help with whatever you may be trying to do.

Comment: @Oded LOL! Although in this case VB *is* **exactly** like C#, so nice comment but you've put it in the wrong question :)

Comment: I'm incredibly relieved to see this question has been closed as not constructive.  For a moment there I almost learned something before the moderation mafia illuminated the folly in this inquisition.  I fear to imagine the anarchy that would ensue had this not been closed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/90424/need-assignment-operator-to-be-overloadable) is their reasoning:

> Thanks for the suggestion! We don't allow you to overload the
>   assignment operator for a type because there is currently no way to
>   ensure that other languages or the .NET Framework itself will honor
>   the assignment operator. The only alternative is to restrict what
>   types that overload the assignment operator can do, but we felt that
>   this would be too restrictive to be generally useful.
>
> Thanks! Paul Vick Technical Lead, VB

There's something called 'Narrowing' and 'Widening' which allows you to define explicit and implicit converters from one type to another, i.e.

```
Dim y as MyClass1
Dim x as MyClass2 = y
```

But that doesn't let change the assignment operator for assigning an instance of the same class, only converting other classes.

See [How to: Define a Conversion Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/yf7b9sy7%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
Class MyClass1
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal p1 As MyClass1) As MyClass2

    End Operator
End Class
```

---

[Same in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx)

> `+=, -=, *=, /=, %=, &=, |=, ^=, <<=, >>=`
>
> Assignment operators cannot be overloaded, but +=, for example, is evaluated using +, which can be overloaded.

`=, ., ?:, ??, ->, =>, f(x), as, checked, unchecked, default, delegate, is, new, sizeof, typeof`

> These operators cannot be overloaded.

With the same [conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx):

```
struct MyType1
{
    ...
    public static explicit operator MyType1(MyType2 src)  //explicit conversion operator
    {
        return new MyType1 { guts = src.guts };
    }
}
```

Comment: Ticket closed as "Won't Fix" in 2004 - rofl. Here's hoping they've since revisited the suggestion.

Comment: Does it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292676/is-there-a-workaround-for-overloading-the-assignment-operator-in-c

Comment: C# doesn't support operator overloads: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx. An ish workaround is to overload operator `+`, since += uses it, but you still can't overload `=`.